# I want to increase a specific column width using fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fpdf

There are three columns in my query and the first one if overextending. So I want to modify the function Calcwidths such that the second column width decreases. Or modify the entire table such that it adjusts according to the cell content.

Please tell me exactly what to do since I do not understand fpdf much.
Thank you.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_MySQL_Table extends FPDF
{
protected $ProcessingTable=false;
protected $aCols=array();
protected $TableX;
protected $HeaderColor;
protected $RowColors;
protected $ColorIndex;

function Header()
{
// Print the table header if necessary
if($this->ProcessingTable)
    $this->TableHeader();
}

function TableHeader()
{
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$this->SetX($this->TableX);
$fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
if($fill)
$this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$thisHeaderColor[2]);
foreach($this->aCols as $col)
    $this->Cell($col['w'],6,$col['c'],1,0,'C',$fill);
$this->Ln();
}

function Row($data)
{
$this->SetX($this->TableX);
$ci=$this->ColorIndex;
$fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
if($fill)
    $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);
foreach($this->aCols as $col)
    $this->Cell($col['w'],5,$data[$col['f']],1,0,$col['a'],$fill);
$this->Ln();
$this->ColorIndex=1-$ci;
}

function CalcWidths($width, $align)
{
// Compute the widths of the columns
$TableWidth=0;
foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
{
    $w=$col['w'];
    if($w==-1)
        $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
    elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
        $w=$w/100*$width;
    $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
    $TableWidth+=$w;
}
// Compute the abscissa of the table
if($align=='C')
    $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
elseif($align=='R')
    $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
else
    $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
}

function AddCol($field=-1, $width=-1, $caption='', $align='L')
{
// Add a column to the table
if($field==-1)
    $field=count($this->aCols);
$this->aCols[]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
}

function Table($con, $query, $prop=array())
{
// Execute query
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con)."    <br>Query: $query");
// Add all columns if none was specified
if(count($this->aCols)==0)
{
    $nb=mysqli_num_fields($res);
    for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
        $this->AddCol();
}
// Retrieve column names when not specified
foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
{
    if($col['c']=='')
    {
        if(is_string($col['f']))
            $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
        else
            $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst(mysqli_fetch_field_direct($res,$col['f'])->name);
    }
}
// Handle properties
if(!isset($prop['width']))
    $prop['width']=0;
if($prop['width']==0)
    $prop['width']=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
if(!isset($prop['align']))
    $prop['align']='C';
if(!isset($prop['padding']))
    $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
$cMargin=$this->cMargin;
$this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
    $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
$this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
if(!isset($prop['color1']))
    $prop['color1']=array();
if(!isset($prop['color2']))
    $prop['color2']=array();
$this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);
// Compute column widths
$this->CalcWidths($prop['width'],$prop['align']);
// Print header
$this->TableHeader();
// Print rows
$this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
$this->ColorIndex=0;
$this->ProcessingTable=true;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    $this->Row($row);
$this->ProcessingTable=false;
$this->cMargin=$cMargin;
$this->aCols=array();
}
}
?>

<?php
session_start();

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
// Title
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Server/URL Details',0,1,'C');
$this->Ln(10);
// Ensure table header is printed
parent::Header();
}
}


$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Server_Name,Server_Status,Server_Type FROM server where ENV_NAME='{$_SESSION['envt_name']}' && ENV_TYPE = '{$_SESSION['envt_type']}'";

$pdf->Table($con,$query);
$pdf->AddPage();
$querytwo = "SELECT DISTINCT URL_Name,URL_Status,URL_Type FROM url where     ENV_NAME='{$_SESSION['envt_name']}' && ENV_TYPE = '{$_SESSION['envt_type']}'";
$pdf->Table($con,$querytwo);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;) I set for second column width 50, you can change it.

```
function CalcWidths($width, $align)
{
// Compute the widths of the columns
$TableWidth=0;
foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
{
    $w=$col['w'];
    if ($i != 1) { 
        if($w==-1)
            $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
        elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
            $w=$w/100*$width;
    } else {
       **//Your custom width for second column**
       $w = 50; 
    }
    $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
    $TableWidth+=$w;
}
// Compute the abscissa of the table
if($align=='C')
    $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
elseif($align=='R')
    $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
else
    $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
}
```